# E2E selenium test using xunit: how to set up one assert per test

Tags: selenium, xunit.net

I have a E2E selenium/C# test that starts from the login page, navigates thro multiple other pages and finishes in logout. Btw, this is one of many E2E tests. Below are the typical steps in Test class:

- Go to login page
- Assert its the correct page
- Login with given credentials
- Assert the page opened is dashboard
- Click on a link
- Assert the new page is the correct page
  .
  .
  .
- Logout

Someone said that there should be only one assert per test. So I have to break them in such a way to have only one assert per test and also only one browser object is created and passed among the tests.

How to resolve this? Or it it necessary to break one assertion per test in the class?

I have the following classes:

- Base class which has constructor, receiving the browser type, to create the the driver and Dispose to
  close all browsers
- LoginPage class that handles related actions like go to the url and logging in. Return the resulting
  dashboard page to Test class
- Other similar classes that represent different pages.

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion! You would have to ask your mysterious _someone_ to explain the reasoning behind their opinion, and how they feel this should be resolved.

Comment: There are no rules for asserts.. It's a common approach to use asserts after each step - think about a regular test case: When I do .... - I should se ...  . So each time you're performing an action, you are making sure that everything is as expected.

Comment: sry for out of topic, i feel here is good place to say what I want to say last 10 years: .NET community is very religious, however using c# we just describe regular state machine the goal of which is just to decrease local entropy while heating the universe as less as possible. There is really 0 magic behind coding, try to understand your someone, probably his case is specific or he is pushing this idea by mistake.